# In prestashop How to pass a value from a php file into a template file

Tags: php, templates, prestashop

In prestashop, i am in need to pass the output value stored in a variable of a php file to a template file within my modules folder.How to pass the smarty variable resultstring output to my template fie.

**php code**

```
<?php

$output = "welcome";

$smarty->assign('resultstring', $output);

?>
```

**template file code**

```
{if $resultstring == 'welcome'}
     <h6>Hai welcome</h6>
{else}
     <h6>not exist </h6>
{/if}
```

Comment: Did you read [this](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Displaying+content+on+the+front-office)?

Comment: To Pefrom this simple if condition do i need to create a module in prestashop?@user2089987

Comment: Do you want to directly access a separate PHP file in your modules folder?

Comment: I want to access the resultstring value present in the php file from any of the template file.If i can access resultstring value from header.tpl file means i can use it in any template file.@yenshirak

Comment: Do you want to assign a global smarty variable that can be accessed from any TPL file?

Comment: Yes already i have assingn a particular value to a smarty variable resultstring.I want to perform a condition gloablly form any tpl file by accessing the resultstring value. @yenshirak

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55916/discussion-between-user2089987-and-yenshirak).

Answer (score 1):

I am also a beginner in Prestashop, but why not to intervene maybe I can give help.

I think you need to create a controller inside of your php file (that you should locate in the root of your module folder), something like:

```
<?php
class displayController extends ModuleFrontController
{

  $output = "welcome";

  $this->context->smarty->assign('resultstring', $output);

  public function initContent()
  {
    parent::initContent();
    $this->setTemplate('template.tpl');
  }


}
```

You can keep the template file as it is.